# SUSE 11 SP4 resolver doesn't query nameservers

Tags: linux, sles, resolv.conf

My resolver is not querying the nameserver.

This command is running the background

```
tcpdump -n -s 0 port 53 &
```

Resolver points to files then dns

```
 # grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
 hosts:  files dns
```

Getent never queries the nameserver (text written is by background tcpdump)

```
     # getent hosts this_wont_exist
     # dig this_wont_exist +short
11:16:56.964399 IP6 2001:9999:999:9999:999:999:0:f.41860 > 2001:9999:999:9999:99:999:9:999.53: 26738+ [1au] A? this_wont_exist. (44)
11:16:57.095274 IP6 2001:9999:999:9999:99:999:0:247.53 > 2001:9999:999:9999:999:999:0:f.41860: 26738 NXDomain 0/1/1 (119)
```

Any ideas?  I have other systems with an identical config and it works fine.  Heck, I think this worked for a while (can't reboot production to see if a reboot fixes it).  Stopping NSCD doesn't help.

System is running SUSE Linux 11 SP4

Comment: Is it the same with `tcpdump -pnni eth0 port 53`. The `-s 0` can drop more packets.

Comment: Try querying `getent hosts www.google.com` and compare the result.

Comment: Other tcpdump queries also don't show a query. Same results with google.  there is no apparent  attempt to query a DNS server.

Comment: Just noticed a big clue.. if I run tcpdump on localhost I see the query going out the IPV4 localhost port. (there is no local DNS server).   Using strace, I also see the connect call.  No connection is attempted to the servers in /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

/etc/resolv.conf had this

```
nameserver ip-addres # hostname
```

I thought that file was replicated to all hosts, but it wasn't!  It doesn't work if you put a comment in the line at all.  I suspect any line with a "#" is ignored, not just the text after the "#"

So much for documentation. :)